# jquery - Create a List of all LIs Name's

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

Given the following block of HTML:

```
<ul id="taglist">
<li><a name="45" href="">Product 1</a></li>
<li><a name="1146" href="">Product 2</a></li>
<li><a name="13437" href="">Product 3</a></li>
<li><a name="51" href="">Product 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible for JQUERY to return a STRING, one variable with the name values:

```
alert(tagliststring);
```

Would alert: 45,1146,13437,51

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `each` function:

```
var names = [];
$('#taglist > li > a').each(function() {
    names.push(this.name);
});
var result = names.join(',');
alert(result);
```

This way, `names` will be an array filled with each individual name, and `result` will be the comma-delimited string that you are looking for.

For more information, see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

An even smaller way of doing this is to use jQuery's `map` function:

```
var names = $('#taglist > li > a').map(function() { return this.name; }).get();
var result = names.join(',');
```

The first example will probably be easier for people to read and understand.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var names = $('#taglist > li > a').map(function() {
  return this.name;
}).get().join(',');
// names will contain the string: "45,1146,13437,51"
```

The `$.map` method allows you to pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

After `$.map`, I use the `get` method, to obtain a plain JavaScript Array object, where I can finally, call the `join` method, to generate a string.

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/uwesi/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var output; 
$('li a').each( function() { output += $(this).attr('name') + ','; });
```

Please note, this will output an extra `,` at the end.

Comment: Is there a way for it not to add a , at the end?